# OAuth consent screen verification - Comply with domain verification requirements

Tags: google-cloud-platform

My OAuth consent screen verification shows me this messsage

```
Comply with domain verification requirements
Ensure your application's domains have completed the Search Console verification process
```

But in my Authorized domains there domains like **.chromiumapp.org or *.extensions.allizom.org/
which ownership I cant verify.

Answer (score 22):

Assume that you already verified your domain and still getting this error, try to do this:

1. Go to your "Google Console" > "OAuth Consent Screen" and under "Publishing status" click "Back to testing"
2. Now you are back in the test mode, click "publish" again
3. You may see some new demands to publish it, which were unknown before. You could follow these demands now.
4. After that, you will see "The Trust and Safety team has received your form." message.

Comment: I was stuck with this message for days, thanks for the advice. Wish google were more clear in its process.

Comment: As you said, the same condition is here How much Time does it Take to verify? Please suggest Is I have to go again to click the button "Prepare For Verification"?

Comment: Hey @tataelm, your answer was perfect. I was stuck in the same problem, the domain was already verified, but the action required was still appearing. After follow your instructions, the action required was gone. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Go to your Google [webmaster](https://search.google.com/search-console) and make sure you can see your domain there,
If not follow the steps on the same page to verify the domain owner.

Comment: This is what helped me. you should put your property with TXT Record so google search could validate it.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't make changes to the DNS of the domain you want to verify, you can try verifying the ownership of your domain by **Verify file or html tag** method. Take a look at [this link](https://cloud.google.com/identity/docs/verify-domain-web) for more information.

Comment: "this link" is broken.