# Verify a custom domain in Github pages

Tags: github, github-pages

I was following these steps: https://docs.github.com/en/pages/configuring-a-custom-domain-for-your-github-pages-site/verifying-your-custom-domain-for-github-pages

The problem I have is when I try to add the domain, I get: Domain cannot end with github.io.

My website is: https://timetap-app.github.io/

Comment: What is your domain name?

Comment: I don't have any domain name apart from that. This is just a simple website for Google Play where I have some necessary info. I'm trying to add Google Play Services and from one comment, it suggested to verify the domain to speed up the process: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69957925/4858133

Comment: We only need to verify the domain if we need to add a custom domain for that page. If you don't want to use any custom domain, you can use the website url github has gave you.

Comment: ah ok. In that case I don't know why Google Play is telling me to check GC Console and GC Console to check GPC. I guess it's just a matter of time